# Problem getting video from DVD

Tags: video, conversion, dvd, ripping, flv

I have a DVD that a customer needs me to pull ~5 minutes of video from, and convert it to FLV to play on their website.

I downloaded AVS Video Converter and tried to use it to convert the VOB file to FLV, with the thought of editing after, and also tried MPEG.  Both times it froze up.  I then tried to just copy the file from the DVD to my hard drive, thinking that maybe the disc access was slowing things down too much.  I got a "Cyclic redundancy" error from Windows while doing that, and it stopped copying.

Is the file corrupted?  Is there any better way to get it from the DVD player?  I only need 5 minutes of 1.5 hours, so if I can avoid converting the entire thing then editing, that would be awesome

Thanks for your help

Comment: Does the DVD actually play - i.e. can you watch the contents in WMP, VLC, whatever?

Comment: It freezes up about 20 minutes in... the section I need is from 5-10

Answer (score 2):

I use [DVD Rip](http://lifehacker.com/355281/dvd-rip-automates-one+click-dvd-ripping) to rip the dvd

then [Free Video Converter](http://www.any-video-converter.com/products/for_video_free/) to convert to an AVi

Then use [NamDub](http://www.van-munster.com/Interests/AnnaChris/AVRconversionNandub.htm) to cut out the scene

Comment: Hasn't really answered the question though.

Comment: i meant try that method to see if its a problem with the video and not with your method

Answer (score 0):

Yes, your disk is corrupted.

You may recover the data that can be read by using a utility such as [Roadkil's Raw Copy](http://www.roadkil.net/program.php?ProgramID=22):

> This program copys a disk as a raw
>   image from one drive directly to
>   another. This utility is designed for
>   people who have faulty drive and want
>   to transfer the data directly to
>   another drive without doing a file by
>   file copy. This saves the need for
>   operating system re-installs and
>   allows drives with an unknown file
>   system to be copied (including from
>   console game machines, data recorders,
>   mac etc). The program has a built in
>   data recovery function which will
>   attempt to recover data from bad
>   sectors to ensure all the available
>   data is restored from the drive. This
>   program is designed to run under
>   NT/XP/2000 or later operating systems.
>   It will run under windows 95/98/Me
>   operating systems but only windows
>   logical drives can be copied.

Or [Unstoppable Copier 4.2](http://www.softpedia.com/get/System/Back-Up-and-Recovery/Unstoppable-Copier.shtml):

> Unstoppable Copier will continue copying the file right to the end; any > unrecoverable data after many retries is replaced with blanks. This will allow you > to truely recover every byte of information that is available for recovery.

You may also try to fix the cd, assuming the damage is minimal by, for example:
[MacGyver Tip: Fix scratched CDs with toothpaste](http://lifehacker.com/155741/macgyver-tip-fix-scratched-cds-with-toothpaste)